# Python 3.3 Pickle Errors for read/write

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm trying to write a program that displays a menu and allows users to write to a file, read from a file, or exit. The file contains a list object, so I'm using a .dat file. I've read the python documentation and loads of 'pickle error' threads on this site, but can't seem to understand why I'm getting the errors I'm getting. I'd love any insight!

**Error for `write_to_file` function:**

```
integer is required
```

As far as I can tell, I'm using the correct form of `open`, which seemed to be what was giving other users trouble with this error, and I can't find anything in the Python documentation about a required integer argument to `pickle.dump` (Also, I'm pretty sure the method I'm using to allow the user to input data to the file is incorrect, but I haven't been able to get past the pickle errors preceding it.)

```
def write_to_file():
    s = open('studentInfo.dat')
    pickle.dump(info, s, 'wb')
    shelve.open(s)
    print(s)
    print("You may now add information to the file:")
    input(s[''])
    s.close()
```

**Error for `read_file` function:**

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: write
```

I have no `'w'` or `'wb'` arguments in this function, and I want it to be a read-only action anyway. Where is the write error hidden?

```
def read_file():
    f = open('studentInfo.dat', 'rb')
    pickle.dump(info, f)
    shelve.open(f, 'rb')
    print("Here is the student information: \n")
    print(f)
    f.close()
```

Here's the full code:

```
#import necessary modules:
import pickle, shelve

# create list object
info = [[("student", "John"),("GPA","4.0"), ("ID", "01234")],
        [("student", "Harry"),("GPA","3.2"), ("ID", "03456")],
        [("student", "Melissa"),("GPA","1.8"), ("ID", "05678")],
        [("student", "Mary"),("GPA","3.5"), ("ID", "07899")]]

#Function Definitions
def write_to_file():
    s = open('studentInfo.dat')
    pickle.dump(info, s, 'wb')
    shelve.open(s)
    print(s)
    print("You may now add information to the file:")
    input(s[''])
    s.close()

def read_file():
    f = open('studentInfo.dat', 'rb')
    pickle.dump(info, f)
    shelve.open(f, 'rb')
    print("Here is the student information: \n")
    print(f)
    f.close()

#def main(): #while loop as program engine, constantly prompt user, display menu, etc.

menu = ("\n0 - Exit the Program",               #Exit
        "\n1 - Add student information",        #Write to file
        "\n2 - Print student information")  #Read file

print(menu)
menuchoice = int(input("Please enter a number that matches the menu option you want: "))
##writetofile = open("studentInfo.dat", "wb")
##printinfo = open("studentInfo.dat", "rb")

if menuchoice == 0:
    input("\nPress the 'enter' key to exit the program.")
elif menuchoice == 1:
    print("You may add a student, gpa, or student ID to the file")
    write_to_file()
elif menuchoice == 2:
    read_file()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the mode parameter to the `open()` call, *not* to `pickle.dump()`:

```
s = open('studentInfo.dat', 'wb')
pickle.dump(info, s)
```

To *load* from an open file, use `pickle.load()`:

```
f = open('studentInfo.dat', 'rb')
info = pickle.load(f)
```

You don't need the `shelve` module and calls here at all. Remove those.

You probably want to use the files as context managers here, closing them automatically:

```
with open('studentInfo.dat', 'wb') as outputfile:
    pickle.dump(info, outputfile)
```

and

```
with open('studentInfo.dat', 'rb') as inputfile:
    info = pickle.load(inputfile)
```

You cannot add just add unstructured additional information to the file after opening; add the new information to `info` *before* pickling `info` to the file:

```
def write_to_file():
    # take input and add that to `info` here.
    # gather a name, GPA and ID into `new_name`, `new_gpa` and `new_id`
    info.append([("student", new_name),("GPA", new_gpa), ("ID", new_id)])

    with open('studentInfo.dat', 'wb') as outputfile:
        pickle.dump(info, outputfile)
```

Your `read_file()` function should probably return the read information, *or* you should make `info` an explicit `global`:

```
def read_file():
    with open('studentInfo.dat', 'rb') as inputfile:
        info = pickle.load(inputfile)
    return info
```

By returning from the function, you can then assign it back to `info` or print it:

```
read_info = read_file()
print("Here is the student information: \n")
print(read_info)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the advice and examples. Definitely fixed my code and taught me a few things. Now I just have to create a menu function that will prompt the user after he or she enters or reads the data. Cheers Martijn!